# What is transactional in Grails?

Tags: grails

What is transactional in a easy explanation or a example? I quite not understand it even reading the [docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/single.html#declarativeTransactions). If i put `transactional = true`, I can rollback if any error is caused, otherwise, if the `transactional = false`, means that I can't rollback?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just to explain the concept of [Transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) using an example.

> FYI: All services are transactional by default which means all the
>   methods with in all services are also transactional by default. But if
>   *you add transaction = true/false* your are breaking the convention so after
>   that you have to mark each of your method transaction or not
>   transactional as needed

So going to the example assume you have a method that calls another five methods:

```
void methodName(){
    task1()
    task2()
    task3()
    task4()
    task5()

}
```

I diagrammed the above method with this:

[image]

Now assume when you call the above method and the execution goes fine executing the first three tasks.

Now the method is diagrammed as follows:
[image]

If the method is transactional and something wicked happened after executing the third task,  all  what is done will be rolledback:
[image]

But if the method is not transactional and something wicked happened after executing the third task, everything done will be committed:

[image]

Transactional in databases context from wiki:

> In an atomic transaction, a series of database operations either all
>   occur, or nothing occurs.

Comment: That clarify a lot to me!

Answer (score 3):

A transaction is an all-or-nothing approach whose aim consists in the maintenance of database integrity through their ACID (atomicity, consistency, isolation, and durability) properties.

Let me quickly go through these:

- **Atomicity**: if one part of the transaction fails, the entire transaction fails, and the database state is left unchanged.
- **Consistency**: any transaction will bring the database from one valid state to another
- **Isolation**: concurrent execution of transactions results in a system state that would be obtained if transactions were executed serially
- **Durability**: once a transaction has been committed, it will remain so, even in the event of power loss, crashes, or errors

(thank you again [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)!)

When the `transactional` property is set to `true` Grails creates a Spring proxy that wraps each method call and provides transaction management.

To sum up, you are right, in the sense that if an error occurs, ACID properties are preserved and the entire operation within the transactional block is rolledback to the previous consistent state.

Answer (score 1):

I did a talk a couple of years ago at GR8Conf on transactions in Grails. It's around 45 minutes. You can find the video and the slide deck [here](http://gr8conf.org/content/eu2013/Presentations/Grails-Transactions).